# INTERSECT between two pseudo (derived) tables in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out whether there are any differences between two pseudo tables  with one column (see if every element in one table is in the other)

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories FULL OUTER JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    FULL OUTER JOIN  OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France')

INTERSECT

    (SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories LEFT JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            LEFT JOIN Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            LEFT JOIN Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France')
```

eg of output:

Top part of query gives for first three results:

```
OrderID
10255
10267
10275
```

Second part of code (below INTERSECT) gives:

```
OrderID
10255
10267
10275
```

Now for some reason the code is not running with the intersection. The code works separately to give me the individual columns for the sub query above and below the INSERSECT, but in its entirety it just doesn't work. Error message I get is:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTERSECT'.

Completion time: 2022-05-23T14:10:06.3560367+01:00
```

Any idea how to fix this? If it helps, the INTERSECT is underlined red.

Thanks.

Comment: In my last job the guy referred to it as pseudo tables. I'm quite new to sql so have no idea what you'd call it. As long as someone understands the question from the post does it really matter?

Comment: Honestly, the only time I've heard Pseudo tables is in reference to the `inserted` and `deleted` objects within a DML `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Most people would talk about nested queries or subqueries, not derived tables, the name used in relational theory. What you posted is an overcomplicated query. The subqueries seem identical except the operation: `FULL JOIN` vs `LEFT JOIN`. Won't INTERSECT simply return the LEFT JOIN results?

Comment: Huh, interestingly if I search ["SQL Server Pseudo tables"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=SQL+Server+Pseudo+tables) I actually get the documentation [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) despite that the word "Pseudo" never appears on the page.

Comment: Also why are those `LEFT JOIN` when you have `WHERE` clause, logically they become `INNER JOIN` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a FROM Clause attempting to run 2 sub selects enclosed within parenthesis.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS a)
```

Yields an error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Adding an alias, however, works fine:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS a) as a
```

Update:

You only have to alias the first query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS a) as a
INTERSECT
    (SELECT 1 AS a)
```

Or, as suggested by RBarryYoung, remove the parenthesis altogether.

Comment: Ah intersting! I was aliasing both the pseudo tables. Why don't I need to alias the second table? When I remove the alias from the second table (and added to first bit), my query worked.

Comment: One follow up question. is parenthesis necessary or even advised in SQL? I put them in to help me logically determine what's going on. Separately, if I have multipe OR and AND statements, how does SQL determine what order to do things if there are no brackets?

Comment: @Noobcoder - That is when I primarily use them myself; to ensure that `AND` and `OR` clauses are evaluated correctly. For logically grouping code, indentation is very useful. And yes, as you c an see in the example provided, it is also perfectly valid using them when you are defining subqueries. 

Why it behaves in this particular manner when using the `INTERSECT`, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks a million SchmitzIT. I'll put the lack of alias in the latter part not working down to a quirk of MS sql server! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the FROM and the outer parenthesis, like this:

```
    SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories FULL OUTER JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    FULL OUTER JOIN  OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France'
INTERSECT
    SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories LEFT JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            LEFT JOIN Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            LEFT JOIN Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France'
```

Comment: To be honest, *all* of those parenthesis can go. They don't add anything to the query, and I suspect that they actually confused the OP, and hence their error.

Comment: I suspect the top query can go as well. The `LEFT JOIN` results are already contained in the `FULL JOIN` results. The rest of the two queries seem to be identical

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, you're right of course.  Generally you only need/want them when mixing outer join types for clarity or control.  (Or when using the alternative syntax for ON clauses which all sane people avoid like the plague).  But I usually try to post answers with minimal changes for new SQL developers, to help minimize their confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, @RBarryYoung . I find that people coming from certain languages to SQL tend to overuse parenthesis and end up with malformed code, such as they have here, and so feel that it's often better to demonstrate that they don't need them at all. Another common example I see is putting the definition of a function or procedure in parenthesis; which causes a syntax error.

Comment: Reason for the full join and left join was to make sure I was getting all the data from both tables. i.e. nothing was being missed by the left join. The idea in the intersect was to see if any values were being missed off. as I get 26 rows via the combined query as the two sub queries, I guess that means i've proved that in my case the two sub queries returns the same result?

Comment: Does anyone know how to find which values DON'T intersect? is it simply a case of writing ```NOT INTERSECT``` in the code?

Comment: @Noobcoder Replace the INTERSECT with EXCEPT in SQL Server (or MINUS in Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting an x before the INTERSECT works. i.e.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories FULL OUTER JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    FULL OUTER JOIN  OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            FULL OUTER JOIN  Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France') x

INTERSECT

    (SELECT Orders.OrderID
    FROM (((Categories LEFT JOIN Products on Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
            LEFT JOIN Orders on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID)
            LEFT JOIN Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
    WHERE CategoryName LIKE 'Dairy%' AND country ='France')
```